# Give an example of a polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree 10 which is reducible modulo 2,3 and 5 but irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: polynomials

Give an example of a polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree 10 which is reducible modulo 2,3 and 5 but irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

I tried to solve this by Eisenstein Criterion,let $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, but I don't know how to let it reducible module 2,3, and 5. Please help me to figure it out! Thank you!

Comment: Try a very simple form...like $x^{10}+2$.  That clearly factors $\pmod 2$  and $\pmod 3$ at least.

Comment: Or, even easier, $x^{10}+30$.   But my first example works as well.

Comment: Simpler yet, $x^2 + 30$?

Comment: @Théophile  The OP specified degree $10$, though of course $x^n+30$ does work for all $n$.

Comment: @lulu Oh, I see; thanks. I missed that.